# Alterar cor e tamanho da borda Menu Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

[image: Preciso diminuir a espessura da borda e a cor do Menu]

Alguém pode me ajudar com essa questao?

Answer (score 2):

A cor da borda do menu é dada pela cor de fundo (background) do menu.
Se você deseja que a cor da borda seja diferente da cor de fundo do menu, tem que configurar separadamente a cor de fundo de cada entrada.

Para a espessura da borda, basta setar o valor em pixels no atributo "border", e o tipo de relevo "flat" para que o tkinter não crie um pseudo-3D com a cor dada.

Então, dada a imagem acima, vamos criar uma janela com menu, fundo preto no menu e borda vermelha:

```
import tkinter

def command():
    pass

def main():
    w = tkinter.Tk()
    menu = tkinter.Menu(w, background="black", foreground="red")
    file_menu = tkinter.Menu(menu, background="red", foreground="red", relief="flat", border=8, tearoff=0)
    opcoes = "Contas User  Usuários  Email Services  Login Cad. Usuário  Variáveis do Sistema  Sair".split("  ")
    for opcao in opcoes:
        file_menu.add_command(label=opcao, command=command, background="black")
    menu.add_cascade(label="Cadastro", menu=file_menu)

    w.config(menu=menu)
    return w

main()
tkinter.mainloop()
```

(este código é para Python 3 - em Python 2 é só trocar "tkinter" por "Tkinter" em todos os pontos)

Se desejar trocar a cor de fundo ou algum outro atributo de uma entrada do menu depois que ela for criada, deve-se usar o método no menu:

```
file_menu.entry_config(0, ...)
```

Onde 0 é o índice da entrada desejada.

Answer (score 0):

Para alterar o tamanho da borda voce usa a opção borderwidth no Frame, pode usar também relief para o tipo de borda  ex:

```
Frame(ondevaioframe, relief = RIDGE, borderwidth = '8')
```

Agora a cor, eu não sei te dizer se tem como mudar.